# C++ ranges view iterators and operator->

Tags: c++

If I perform a transform view operation I noticed that the view iterator does not support the operator->. So in code terms

```
void transform_view( )
{
    struct Z { int a; };

    std::ranges::single_view view { Z { 99 } };

    auto transform_view { std::ranges::views::transform( view, []( auto const& z ){ return Z { z.a + 10 }; } ) };

    // The operator-> does not compile here as there is none defined
    // auto transform_view_first_value { transform_view.begin( )->a };
}
```

This is "as expected" as the standard in 24.7.6.3 which defines range.transform.iterator does not have an operator->.

I found this a bit surprising and tried to understand why it would not have one. I could not find and overiew in the standard or various web places of what is generally expected of view iterators and why in particular there is no operator-> on at least some of them.

Does anyone know the answer or a good source of information on this?

Comment: Probably as the `->` operator might have to create a temporary value and returning a pointer would be tricky/impossible and if you call `->` multiple times on the same iterator position it'd also be inefficient

Answer (score 3):

Simplifying, the prototype for the `operator->` is:

```
T* operator->();
```

In order to create this operator, you must be able to return a pointer to T and this pointer must be valid after you return from the operator. So, the iterator must store a temporary object for that pointer and control its life cycle.

This would create some problems:

- Iterators are assumed to be cheap to store, but now they may contain a hidden copy of T.
- It goes against one of the design rationales: [ranges cannot own elements](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2014/n4128.html#ranges-cannot-own-elements).
- One of the design guidelines for ranges is that [adaptors are lazy evaluated](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2014/n4128.html#range-adaptors-are-lazy-algorithms%C2%A0), so the object would be created when the `operator->` is called. Every call to the operator should destroy the internal object and return a new pointer. If we decide to keep the object as a cache, we must add more logic to the iterator to control the life cycle and invalidation of the object.

It also raises some questions that must be answered by the standard: Who owns that object? Is it safe to modify it? What happens when the iterator is copied? What happens when the iterator is moved? When is the pointer invalidated?

I think `operator->` was not added because it makes the implementation more difficult, but it does not add any improvement: you can use `operator*` to achieve the same behaviour. However, this operator returns a copy of T, so the owner of the object and its life cycle is clear.

Comment: so, basically you're saying range is view and should be lightweight.

Comment: also, the `operator->` does not need to return `T*`

Comment: I think I can summarize that `operator->` creates more problems than it solves. Yes, you are right, `operator->` does not need to return T*. The only option I can think that can solve these problems is returning something like std::unique_ptr<T>, but I think it only adds more complexity.